# How do I select a substring from two different patindex?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many different types of string, but they all follow the two same patterns:

```
ABC123-S-XYZ789
ABC123-P-XYZ789
```

QUESTION 1:

I know how I can extract the first part: ABC123
But how do I extract the second part??? XYZ789

QUESTION 2:

I can't tell beforehand if the string follows the -S- pattern or the -P- pattern, it can be different each time. Anyone who know how I can solve this?

Thanks! / Sophie

Comment: Add the tag of your database system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @a LIKE '%-S-%' THEN right(@a, CHARINDEX('-S-', @a)-1)
WHEN @a LIKE '%-P-%' THEN right(@a, CHARINDEX('-P-', @a)-1) 
ELSE NULL END AS 'ColName'
FROM tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(100) = 'ABC123-S-XYZ789'

SELECT
    FirstPart = SUBSTRING(
        @Input,
        1,
        CHARINDEX('-', @Input) - 1),

    SecondPart = SUBSTRING(
        @Input,
        LEN(@Input) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@Input)) + 2,
        100),

    Pattern = CASE 
        WHEN @Input LIKE '%-S-%' THEN 'S'
        WHEN @Input LIKE '%-P-%' THEN 'P' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parsename()` if the string has always this kind of parts such as  `ABC123-S-XYZ789`

```
select col, parsename(replace(col, '-', '.'), 1)
```

However, the `parsename()` requires the *SQL Server+12* if not then you can use `reverse()`

```
select col, reverse(left(reverse(col), charindex('-', reverse(col))-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server 2016 or newer, you can use [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql)

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (string VARCHAR(100));

INSERT #temp VALUES ('ABC123-S-XYZ789'),('ABC123-P-XYZ789');

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY string ORDER BY string) 
    FROM #temp t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.string, '-');
```

> I can't tell beforehand if the string folllows the -S- pattern or the -P- pattern

You can then use a CTE to get a specific part of the string:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY string ORDER BY string) rn
        FROM #temp t
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.string, '-')
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rn = 2
```